# Request to re-open 1275693

Tags: support, reopen-request

It's been marked as too broad but I did some editing and I think I narrowed things down. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1275693/response-time-always-late-when-gaming) is the link. I've sent flags to moderators to re-open it after my editing but they declined them saying "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". I never had problems like that one and it's very strange and hard to troubleshoot, I did as much as I could and I would like some other people that know more to maybe analyze it and try to help me. Can a moderator re-open that question?

Comment: "You haven't put forward a convincing argument, nor have you linked to the question" shamelessly copied from a comment on your deleted question.

Comment: Please do not simply delete and re-ask meta questions when you get downvotes or you need to edit it to clarify. Edit your question to clarify and justify your position.

Comment: @DavidPostill plagiarism!

Comment: @Burgi lol .....

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are referring to [Response time always late when gaming](https://superuser.com/questions/1275693/response-time-always-late-when-gaming).

You have edited the question so it has gone into the reopen queue where users with the appropriate privilege can vote to reopen if they feel the edited question is worth reopening.

My personal opinion is that the question is still too broad and cannot be answered with the information provided.

Comment: It has already passed through the reopen queue without anyone believing it should be reopened. https://superuser.com/review/reopen/713716

Comment: @Mokubai So I'm not alone in my opinion. As a mod I no longer vote in the queues as my vote would be binding. I prefer to let the community hive mind make such decisions :)

Comment: @DavidPostill do you have any other recommendations as to what more info should I provide

Comment: @IgorPavkovic Unfortunately no. I'm no expert on this kind of issue.